# H2 - Select of a Join of Two Tables

Tags: mysql, join, h2

Trying to select the combination of two sub selects. This works fine in MySQL, but does not work in my H2 liquibase instance.

In H2 it fails with a:

> Error: Error executing SQL. Syntax error in SQL statement

And prints out the entire input.

I turned on H2 code formatting in Intellij and it shows an error around the named table `t1`. Not sure how to do a join with sub selects in H2.

```
SELECT name, store_code, min, max, message
 FROM (
  (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT name, level, store_code
    FROM
      name_mapping
    WHERE
      store_code in ('us', 'ca')
  ) t1
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT id as 'level', 5 as 'min', 7 as 'max', 'two' as 'message' from level where description='slow'
    UNION SELECT id as 'level', 3 as 'min', 5 as 'max', 'two' as 'message' from level where description='medium'
    UNION SELECT id as 'level', 1 as 'min', NULL as 'max', 'one' as 'message' from level where description='fast'
  ) t2
  ON t1.level = t2.level
)
GROUP BY name, store_code, min, max, message;
```

Trying to insert new information into a new table based on the join. The `level` table has speed information based on level id (we have to look up by description since the id is auto-incremented). I want to join that will all the names for those speed levels which are contained in another table `name_mapping` joined on the level id.

---

**Update**

This also fails with a Syntax Error in H2 but works great in MySQL:

```
 select * from ( (select 'a') t1 join (select 'a') t2 on t1.a=t2.a );
```

Comment: What does "not wirk in my H2" means in detail? Any error?

Comment: Updated the question with the error message and location.

Comment: Depending on your data, with `CREATE VIEW T2 AS
SELECT id as 'level', 5 as 'min', 7 as 'max', 'two' as 'message' from level where description='slow'
UNION
SELECT id as 'level', 3 as 'min', 5 as 'max', 'two' as 'message' from level where description='medium'
UNION
SELECT id as 'level', 1 as 'min', NULL as 'max', 'one' as 'message' from level where description='fast'
;` you might be lucky get the same result with `SELECT DISTINCT
T1.name
, T1.level
, T1.store_code
, T2.min
, T2.max
, T2.message
FROM name_mapping T1
JOIN T2
ON T1.level = t2.level
WHERE T1.store_code in ('us', 'ca')
;`.

Comment: ... which might be easier to port to H2. -- Here is a quick [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd0c80/1) to verify the syntax... At this time, your `GROUP BY` is essentially a(nother) `DISTINCT` as you are not using any function. -- Didn't make up any data as the approach will rise or fall with the data's particularities. --- The joining sub-select in your update relies on MySQL specifics, which are not in line with the SQL standard (there is no `FROM` clause in there). Can't tell, whether or not this is failing the statement in H2.